Podman container start with entrypont is not waiting for the task complete and exits
I have a container to start which has an entry-point which will run a shell script and it runs for pretty long time say 1 hour.
During docker it was running fine and it never exited the container unless the entire task is complete. But when i am using pod-man, it immediately exits but the process is still running inside a container.
This is the command i am using for starting the container
podman container start -ai `podman ps -a | grep "mycontainer" | awk '{ print $1 }'` 
Please let me know if anyone has a solution for this.
